# WAMP server 3.0.6 error "The service 'wampmysqld64' is NOT started"

Tags: wampserver, wamp64

Wamp server icon is not turned to green. Apache server is started successfully but my wampmysqld64 is not started. Below is the Mysql error log.

```
2016-11-16T18:56:08.140148Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
2016-11-16T18:56:09.740961Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
wampmysqld64: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2016-11-16T18:56:10.232737Z 0 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2016-11-16T18:56:10.354885Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 56a59712-ac2e-11e6-99ca-208984e4e31f.
2016-11-16T18:56:10.436871Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2016-11-16T18:56:10.446880Z 0 [Warning] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables

2016-11-16T18:56:10.448881Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
2016-11-16T18:56:10.449881Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I would guess that the install did not run correctly. Did you run the install as an Administrator. It has to be run as an administrator

Comment: Yes, I've tried to run it as administrator but it's not working. 
@user3284463 I've tried to delete files (ibdata1, ib_logfile1, ib_logfile0) under data folder and restart WAMP server. Try to change mysql port 3306 to 3307 but no luck. I've checked data folder path in my.ini It is correct.